# Create multiple select depending on previous choices with values from DB

Tags: php, mysql, forms, select

Can anybody help me how to obtain this with (php/js or jquery)? I'm still beginner.

I have table in mysql which contains beyond other (and I don't know it before checking the DB)

- name of company (for ex. Abc, Def...)
- year
- month
- and some data for each month different ones

I need to create a form which in first *select* field I load available *name of company*. When user select one of them (*Abc*) it should display only appropriate year - filled for that company (*2000, 2008, 2012*) and etc. for (selected year just filled month).

I've done working the first part (bellow) but how to handle with different selects for different companies if I don't know possible combinations without checking DB.

```
<?php 
echo "Select company: <select name=\"company\">";
    $con=connect();
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Company");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value=\"".$row['Name']."\">".$row['Name']."</option>";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    echo "</select><br>";
?>
```

Comment: try writing something and tell us what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    in order to do that you need to use Ajax , suppose the ajax file is relatedYears.php
    in relatedYears.php, write the following code 

    <?php 
    $con=connect();
    $result="";

    //this is the company name sent by url using ajax in the main page
    $company_name= $_GET['company_name'];

    $query= "SELECT years FROM COMPANY WHERE company = $company_name";
    $x=mysql_query($query) or die('error query');
    $years=array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($x))
      $years[]= $row[0];

    foreach($years as $year)
      $results .= "<option value='".$year."'>".$year."</option>";


    echo $results;
    ?>
```